# Acrobat 2020 editing the Header or Footer in a PDF Document

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, adobe, acrobat

I use Acrobat 2020 (pro) to edit a large document. When I insert a "Header" I can use the tool to edit "headers and footers" like in a Word Document.
https://www.adobe.com/au/acrobat/hub/how-to/how-to-use-headers-footers-in-pdfs.html
I have to do this because the document is puzzled of 100 different documents and is printed at the end.
The header contains a Page-Number and when I update the header, Acrobat will find the pagenumbers in all this textboxes and update the numbers (or text).
I made a sample of a random document. The pagenumbers I look for are the one of the top. (there is not on every page a number)
[sample_Doc](https://www.theostern.de/yo2/FuerFrageKopfzeile.pdf)
The pagenumbers are made by Acrobat and if I add a page, Acrobat will count the pages new when I make an update.
Now, I will find this pagenumbers in the document and a textbox nearby. Is there anybody who knows how to do this? Acrobat will find it, then eg VBA or Java Script will find it too.
But how?

Comment: »unless it was deliberately tagged as a page number«
that's what I'm looking for. Acrobat self finds it, so it must be possible for any code to find  it too. The tipp with the SDK may be helpful. Didn't knew that there is one. *